# bootstrap drop down menu transparent button

Tags: html, css, angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown > button').mousedown(function(){
    $(this).addClass('redClass');
    $('.dropdown').addClass('redClass');
  });
  
  $('.dropdown > button').mouseup(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('redClass');
    $('.dropdown').removeClass('redClass');
  });
  $('.dropdown > button').click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('redClass');
    $('.dropdown').addClass('redClass');
  });
  $('.dropdown > button').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).addClass('redClass');
    $('.dropdown').addClass('redClass');
  });
  
  
})
```

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}

.redClass {
  background: transparent;  
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.transparentClass{
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
                                       
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Home
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
      
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to design a bootstrap drop down for my angular2 application.I am running into issues.I want a single drop down menu when the user clicks the caret only.But even if I click outside the caret the dropdown menu shows.Another issue is I want both the menu and sub menu to have transparent color whether hovered or clicked.I tried the below css for hover and active,it didn't work.

```
.dropdown > button {
  background-color: transparent;  
}


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Home
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>About us</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no way to select parent of an element with css. You can use jQuery to do that:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.dropdown > button').mousedown(function(){
    $(this).addClass('redClass');
    $('.dropdown').addClass('redClass');
  });
  
  $('.dropdown > button').mouseup(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('redClass');
    $('.dropdown').removeClass('redClass');
  });
})
```

```css
.redClass {
  background: #f00;  
}

.transparentClass{
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Home
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>About us</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: And about the caret question- I want the drop down only when I click the caret not the menu button.

Comment: hmm, maybe I have had misunderstood your requirement, could you provide a working JSFiddle?

Comment: Here it is. I want the button to my completely transparent in color whether I move,enter,I press mouse button or click..I used your jquery code it is not working exactly as I expect.I want the submenu drop down to show when I click the caret ( the down arrow) but it just drops down the menu when I click the home button as well. The user would choose if he wants to go to the drop down by clicking the caret. Here is the jsfiddle you asked for  https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/33754/

Comment: And also when moving the mouse over About US changes the background color of the submenu to blue.It should be transparent.

Comment: hmm, I th you should add your JSFIddle to your question (edit question), I will take a look later cuz I'm at work now